# Elasticsearch searching by ID

Tags: elasticsearch

I got problem with searching by ID. One of my index is getting crazy.

Request:
`http://mydomain/myindex/mytype/pkfCkYP4Tam19HWjJAzekw`

Response:
`"found:true"`

Request:
`http://mydomain/myindex/mytype/pkfCkYP4Tam19HWjJAzekw`

Response:
`"found:false"`

Request:
`..../myindex/mytype/pkfCkYP4Tam19HWjJAzekw`

Response:
`"found:true"`

Clearly I see is existing, but sometimes is getting not found.
What can I do?

Comment: Try with `http://mydomain/myindex/mytype/pkfCkYP4Tam19HWjJAzekw?preference=_primary`

Comment: This can sometimes happen if on clusters with several nodes of which one or more are out of sync. Is your cluster health green?